# For Loop with list if statement to check if length item smaller then not working in for loop

Tags: batch-file

i got a input list that contains string/numbers example (1,100,200,300,5000,etc)
i want a for loop to go over it and check if x length is smaller then 4

i tried so many combination it just doesn't work when the if is in the for loop but i need to have it in there since it needs to test it on a bunch of numbers

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for %%x in ("1" "10" "100" "1000" "10000") do (
    if %%x:~4% == "" (
        echo "Length is not bigger than 4 characters."
    ) else (
        echo "Length is bigger than 4 characters."
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: You cannot do string substitution or substrings with the `FOR` meta-variable.  It needs to be assigned to an environmental variable first.

Comment: presuming the numbers are not 0 prefixed, even that is not necessary for the purpose. Just use `If %%~x LSS 1000 (Command) Else (Other command)`

Comment: @T3RR0R Works Thx i can do LSS 9999 to see if its smaller or bigger then 4 long 
for %%x in ("1" "10" "100" "1000" "10000") do (
    if %%~x LSS 9999 (
        echo "%%~x Length is not bigger than 4 characters."
    ) else (
        echo "%%~x Length is bigger than 4 characters."
    )
)